# How do I create a base page event that fires after the derived page's load event?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, page-lifecycle

How do I create a new event in a base page class that fires after all derived pages have fired their load events **but before** any controls fire their load events.

The following code fires the event before the derived page's load event. I want it to fire the event after the derived page's load event but before all control load events:

Base Class:

```
Public Event FirstLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        RaiseEvent FirstLoad(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Derived Class:

```
Private Sub Page_FirstLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FirstLoad

    'Stuff here happens before controls load but only on first page loads'

End Sub
```

Comment: The way that I've typically seen this handled is to add 
base.Load()
at the end of the derived pages Load events, but I'm guessing you're after something more DRY

Comment: @kekekela Yeah I would like to remove the need for derived page's to know that this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this behavior to work properly by overriding the base page's OnLoad method and within that call the base's OnLoad method as per usual, then raise the event that you wish to fire after all of the loads have occurred.

**Base Class:**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        RaiseEvent FirstLoad(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```